# Datagrid is not binding when using ObservableCollection<object>

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Hi i am new silverlight application development. i want to bind a data grid from code behind
for that i have

```
ObservableCollection<object> GridDataSource
```

As datasource, and i use it as

```
 dgAvailibilityOption.ItemsSource = GridDataSource;
```

Now despite this data grid not showing any records. For a check if i bind

```
List<int> testint = new List<int>();
//Add data to list 1 to 10 e.g
dgAvailibilityOption.ItemsSource = testint
```

then datagrid shows perfect rsults as expected
Now my qiestion is that, is there any problem in taking  ObservableCollection type for binding the datagrid??

Comment: Does your GridDataSource has items in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to List while assigning to datagrid,

Also check you have items inside the collection,

```
dgAvailibilityOption.ItemsSource = GridDataSource.ToList();
```

I assume you have, AutoGenerateColumns to be true in  GridDataSource.

Comment: yes Sajeetharan, problem was AutoGenerateColums was "false" in XAML.Also i am binding viewmodel instead of generic "object". and thats solved my prob. Thanks 4 your time... :)